# XMR-stak CPU and GPU hashrate optimisation

Tags: hashrate

I have just set up XMR-stak on my PC (i7 5820K, 32GB DDR4, GTX960 4GB) and am looking to optimise my Hashrates.

The CPU setup is currently as XMR-stak set it up on first run, and delivers around 350-400 H/s (Is this as expected?)

The GPU is slightly modified as I was getting huge system lags, so I adjusted the Threads down from 30 as set by XMR-stak, to 12, with the unintended benefit of more than doubling the GPU Hashrate to over 250 H/s, which leads me to believe that there is potential to significantly optimise for both CPU and GPU.

How can I go about optimising my rates?